Migrate JAX-RS project from Jetty to OpenLiberty
I would like to migrate a simple JAX-RS project from Jetty to OpenLiberty.
The problem are two methods of the ResourceConfig class (Jersey's), that are called at the end of the constructor to configure the server. How can I implement it in OpenLiberty ? I think that configuring the server.xml properly might be enough. Any advices ?
(The JAX-RS project is hosted here)
@ApplicationPath("/api/*")
public class Application extends ResourceConfig {

    public Application() {
        // 
        // jakarta.ws.rs.core.Feature feature = ... 
        //
        register(feature);
        packages("io.agrest.example.api");
    }
}


First, you'll need to extend javax.ws.rs.core.Application/jakarta.ws.rs.core.Application instead of ResourceConfig.
Second, you'll need to enable the appropriate JAX-RS feature in the server.xml by adding the appropriate feature to the <featureManager> element.
Here are a list of the JAX-RS features based on EE version:

EE7: jaxrs-2.0
EE8: jaxrs-2.1
EE9: restfulWS-3.0
EE10: restfulWS-3.1
EE11: restfulWS-4.0

Example:
<server>
    <featureManager>
        <feature>jaxrs-2.0</feature>
    </featureManager>
</server>

Lastly, you'll need to register your JAX-RS Resources/Providers.
By default, JAX-RS will scan your application for classes annotated with @Provider or @Path and automatically register them.
If you want more control, you can use the (legacy) Application.getClasses() or Application.getSingletons() methods to register providers and singletons. This can be useful to prevent the automatic registration of JAX-RS providers that may be included in bundled third-party dependencies.
Example:
@ApplicationPath("/")
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
        Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
        classes.add(MyResource.class);
        return classes;
    }
}

